# Route traffic between two Azure site-to-site VPN locations

Tags: azure, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking, ubiquiti-edgerouter

I have a single Azure virtual network gateway running the "Basic" VPN SKU (MainVGW) in "Route-based" mode in the Australia East region.  MainVGW has two "Connections" (BR and MH) which are IPsec Site-to-Site VPN connections to two separate sites (SITE 1 and SITE 2).  I then have a single VM (TestVM) running in the same region.  Each remote site uses a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter which is configured to connect to its IPsec VPN and tunnel traffic across it using a VTI with static routes (BRrouter and MHrouter).  Each site also has a PC connected to the router with an IP in the local range (BRtestPC and MHtestPC)

[Here is the network layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1fUS.png)

The VPN connections work well in the sense that from each site the test PC (BRtestPC or MHtestPC) can communicate with TestVM on Azure.  However, **I cannot communicate from BRtestPC to MHtestPC** through the MainVGW, even though routers at each end have a separate static route to pass traffic through MainVGW to the other site.  I also can't ping BRrouter from MHrouter or vice versa, although both can ping TestVM successfully.

The documentation I have read seems to indicate that this should work without any additional configuration.  There is some information about what to do if running policy-based routing here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-connect-multiple-policybased-rm-ps but again, this seems to indicate no additional information required for route-based connections.

I think that the static routes are are configured properly on my routers and feel like there must be a setting on the Azure side preventing traffic flow between IPsec Site-to-Site VPN connections that I'm somehow missing - Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Next to using UDR, you can also use [BGP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-bgp-overview#transitrouting) on you VPN devices. This requires however that you'll use a VpnGw1 SKU or higher.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that you might need User Defined Routes on the Azure vNET pointing the traffic to the correct tunnel/azure gateway endpoint for each on-prem network

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-portal

**RouteName**:  RouteSite1

**Addressprefix**:  10.1.100.1/16.

**Next hop type**:  Virtual appliance (Tunnel/endpoint pointing towards Site1)